# How do I call to a line in a data file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to load data from a .txt file, but I cannot figure out how to refer to the rows and columns that I want.

I have normally used code such as follows:

```
a = []
b = []

for line in file:
 if line[0] != 'x':

    False
 else:
    fields = (line.strip()).split('\t')
    a.append(fields[0])
    b.append(fields[1])
```

My issue is that the lines with the data I want do not all start with the same character like other files I have opened. The first line of data I want begins with a float (0.0) and goes up to 5300.0. This is column a. It is separated by a tab from the second column I need, b.

Comment: Can you share your full code, as well as some (test?) data? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment, so I apologize, can you post the contents of the file and explain what you need reached further?

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the data from a .txt file, you can use the file handling

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
data1 = f.read()
data2 = f.readlines()
data3 = f.readline()
f.close()
```

**Explanation**

- `data1` would have all the data as it is from the txt file and is a `str` type
- `data2` would have all the lines in a `list` type `['line1','line2','line3'...]`
- `data3` would read just the first line and the output it `str` type. You can use `read(2)` to read first 2 lines as well.

If you're looking for a more complex output, please post an expected output with the contents of the file - and I'll assist you with the writing the code